# PHP Custom command parser

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Im making a telegram bot and its very hard to get input value from string. My goal is to make my command is easy to write and easy to understand. This is some example command i got from client message

```
,simpleImage. query Dark background. width 200. height 200. text %fortune_teller%
```

That should be an array like this

```
[simple_image][query] => 'Dark background'
[simple_image][width] => '200'
[simple_image][height] => '200'
[simple_image][text] => '%fortune_teller%'
```

and for empty argument should like this

```
,sayHello. %custom_id%
[say_hello] => '%custom_id%'
```

But i have some problem when i try input some japanese text and special character like `\, *, &, |, et cetera` on

```
,cmd. cat files.txt 2>/dev/null && find $HOME -type f -iname \*.mp3 -delete
```

This is some code i write so far

```php
<?php

function parse($string) {
    preg_match_all("/,?([a-z_]+)?\..([a-z]+)\s([a-z\s%_]+)/", $string, $tmp);
    $query = array_combine($tmp[2], $tmp[3]);

    if(!empty($tmp[1])) {
        return array_merge([$tmp[1][0]=>true], $query);
    }
}
var_dump(parse($update['message']));
```

Comment: What should be the result for the input that doesn't work? Why isn't there any dots like in your first sample? And why is `simple_image` in the resulting array for your first sample when the command name is `simpleImage`?

Comment: That is my next plan replacing upper case to underscores + lowercase, i have parse issue, when i tried input some special chars and unicode it does't work, returning null from array_merge

Comment: No, what I mean is, in your first sample, your arguments seem separated by dots (the `.` character). In the second one, it's not the case. What are the rules for parsing your commands? It's pretty unclear based on those two examples. Also, again, please show clearly what the result should be for that second one.

Comment: Oh the `\..`, sorry i forgot that, but im sure method name with comma prefix and end with a dot does't working for the shell command's string, im searching for command parser libraries around the packagist but there is nothing fit for this problems. Let me edit btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I virtually never recommend named capture groups because they just bloat the pattern and the output array of matches, but for those who prefer them, you might use this:

```
~(?:^,(?<COMMANDS>[^.]+)|\G(?!^))\.(?= )(?: (?<KEYS>\S+))? (?<VALUES>.+?(?=\. |$))~
```

Otherwise:

```
~~(?:^,([^.]+)|\G(?!^))\.(?= )(?: (\S+))? (.+?(?=\. |$))~~
```

([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LX1aqW/1/))

Effectively, you should use `\G` (continue metacharacter) to continue matching a variable number of sequences after the leading command substring.  My pattern relies on the fact that the command and subsequent key-value pairs are delimited by dots that are immediately followed by a space.  If you cannot 100% rely on this delimiting sequence, then you need to resolve this issue before trying to move forward.

Once you have the matches array ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QOusX)), you merely need to iterate it to build  the desired output structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2psop))

```
$commands = [
    ',simpleImage. query Dark background. width 200. height 200. text %fortune_teller%',
    ',sayHello. %custom_id%',
    ',cmd. cat files.txt 2>/dev/null && find $HOME -type f -iname \*.mp3 -delete',
];

foreach ($commands as $command) {
    $result = [];
    if (preg_match_all('~(?:^,([^.]+)|\G(?!^))\.(?= )(?: (\S+))? (.+?(?=\. |$))~', $command, $out)) {
        foreach ($out[2] as $index => $subKey) {
            if (strlen($subKey)) {
                $result[$out[1][0]][$subKey] = $out[3][$index];
            } else {
                $result[$out[1][0]] = $out[3][$index];
            }
        }
    }
    echo var_export($result, true) . "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  'simpleImage' => 
  array (
    'query' => 'Dark background',
    'width' => '200',
    'height' => '200',
    'text' => '%fortune_teller%',
  ),
)
---
array (
  'sayHello' => '%custom_id%',
)
---
array (
  'cmd' => 
  array (
    'cat' => 'files.txt 2>/dev/null && find $HOME -type f -iname \\*.mp3 -delete',
  ),
)
---
```